# I am trying to avoid a for loop in r using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to avoid a for loop... 
I am posting a code example to understand what I want to achieve, which is to create a new column with a string summarizing all the data table as:

> columnname1_value1,columnname2_value2..... etc

My question is: How can I use a smart R function to achieve this result, without using the for loop.

```
library(data.table)
test<-as.data.table(mtcars)
ar<-list()
nam<-names(test)
for(i in 1:test[,.N]){
  ar[[i]]<-paste(paste(nam,test[i],sep="_"),collapse=",")
}
test[,string:=as.data.table(unlist(ar))]
```

I would like to use something like:

```
test[,string:=paste(paste(nam,THEROW,sep="_"),collapse=",")]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: updated... hopefully the question is clear now

Comment: Try `do.call(paste, ..`

Comment: Ok. I think this is a bad idea, but one somewhat shorter way is `test[, do.call(function(...) paste(..., sep=","), Map(paste,names(test),.SD, sep="_"))]`

Comment: Or without the function call `test[, do.call(paste, c(.SD, list(sep=",")))]`

Comment: @Frank that works nicely... I didn't even know that you could do half of the things you did there